# functions calls order in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I discovered the trace function in OCaml to follow functions calls. I tried it with fibonacci however the order of function calls was not the one I was expecting. In my code I call `fib (n - 1)` first then `fib (n - 2)` but, with trace, it tells me that `fib (n - 2)` is actually called first. What is the reason?

```
let rec fib n = 
    if n < 2 then 1
    else fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2);;
```

When I trace `fib 3` I get:

```
fib <-- 3
fib <-- 1
fib --> 1
fib <-- 2
fib <-- 0
fib --> 1
fib <-- 1
fib --> 1
fib --> 2
fib --> 3
- : int = 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function contains: `fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)`

The order in which the operands of `+` are evaluated is unspecified. The bytecode OCaml compiler and the native OCaml compiler can even use different orders. For whatever reason, the compiler you used simply chose to generate code that evaluates `fib (n - 2)` first, then `fib (n - 1)`, then computes the sum.