# Order of Evaluation of Arguments in Ocaml

Tags: function, functional-programming, arguments, ocaml

I would like to know why does ocaml evaluate the calls from right to left, is that a FP principle or it doesn't matter at all to a FP language ?

A quicksort example :

```
let rec qs = function
    | [] -> []
    | h::t -> let l, r = List.partition ((>) h) t in
    List.iter (fun e -> print_int e; print_char ' ') l; Printf.printf " <<%d>> " h;
    List.iter (fun e -> print_int e; print_char ' ') r; print_char '\n';
    (qs l)@(h::qs r)
```

In my example the call to `(qs r)` is evaluated first and then `(qs l)` but I expected it to be otherwise.

```
# qs [5;43;1;10;2];;
1 2  <<5>> 43 10 
10   <<43>> 
     <<10>> 
     <<1>> 2 
     <<2>> 
- : int list = [1; 2; 5; 10; 43]
```

EDIT :

from https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora029.html

> In Objective CAML, the order of evaluation of arguments is not
>   specified. As it happens, today all implementations of Objective CAML
>   evaluate arguments from left to right. All the same, making use of
>   this implementation feature could turn out to be dangerous if future
>   versions of the language modify the implementation.

Comment: That's funny, I asked this very question a few weeks ago, even though it usually never comes up. :)

Comment: @RichouHunter look at mine :) it will still have 0 votes in the next months

Comment: @Oleg Why would you expect some votes for this question ? If you just wrote `[ocaml] order evaluation` in the search bar, you would have found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746442/function-returns-list-in-reverse-order-in-ocaml/36746891#36746891 or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548589/functions-calls-order-in-ocaml/35548754#35548754. Here's how I searched : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bocaml%5D+order+evaluation

Comment: Same for @RichouHunter, just try to find if someone already asked the question before asking it yourself. Usually, if it looks like a trivial matter, there will be someone who answered to it.

Comment: questions with title like : function returns list in reverse order in ocaml, don't make me read their body , it's not a clue that  it is about order of argument evaluation and yes my question is a duplicate , my bad because I searched in google this : https://www.google.de/search?q=order+of+ocaml+argument+evaluation&oq=order+of+ocaml+argument+evaluation&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.10135j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=order+of+argument+evaluation+in+ocaml+&* and not directly on SO.

Comment: Well, you'll know for the next time, then.

Comment: @Lhooq, the question was asked on GitHub, about a pull request of mine. :)

Comment: Actually, the question on your PR was about the usefulness of unspecified evaluation order which is not the question Oleg asked. Then, since you just wrote "I asked this very question a few weeks ago", it seems normal that I assumed you actually asked this very question and told you to find answers before asking. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of evaluation of arguments to a function is not specified in OCaml.

This is documented in [Section 6.7 of the manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html).

In essence this gives the greatest possible freedom to the system (compiler or interpreter) to evaluate expressions in an order that is advantageous in some way. It means you (as an OCaml programmer) must write code that doesn't depend on the order of evaluation.

If your code is purely functional, its behavior can't depend on the order. So you need to be careful only when writing code with effects.

**Update**

If you care about order, use `let`:

```
let a = <expr1> in
let b = <expr2> in
f a b
```

Or, more generally:

```
let f = <expr0> in
let a = <expr1> in
let b = <expr2> in
f a b
```

**Update 2**

For what it's worth, the book you cite above was published in 2002. A lot has changed since then, including the name of the language. A more current resource is [Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org).

Comment: but Ocaml has also an OOP side (for now, unkown to me), aren't there any examples where the order would matter ?

Comment: It's not at all difficult to produce examples (with or without the OOP subsystem) where different argument evaluation orders produce different behaviors. Such code has unspecified behavior, so you shouldn't write code like that :-)

Comment: so that's our contract :) ? write code which has the same deterministic behaviour, for any order of parameter evaluation .

Comment: Yes, that's it. It's quite easy if you write mostly functional code. Or in general don't have side effects in expressions that are function arguments. Use `let` if you care about order (see above).